# Get X window id from process in bash

Tags: bash, xorg

Is there any bash tool/warper that could tell which x window(s) has been created by specific process ?

Comment: I don't think so. There are too many layers of abstraction between them.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What's the higher level goal you're trying to achieve with this, there may be a better approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
wmctrl -lp
```

gives me the windows and their PIDs. Sample output:

```
0x04c00022  0 2168   ciro ciro.santilli - Skype™
0x03c00014  0 2154   ciro Krusader
0x03200022  0 2181   ciro Guake!
...
```

Comment: What if I don't have wm running ?

Comment: Sorry, I just wanted to start x application on clear x server and assign vnc server to it by xid. I though that I don't need any wm for it, but anyway, thanks for helping. I'll search more or run some simple wm with wmctrl support.

Comment: You don't need WM - its app responsibility to assign pid to its main window `_NET_WM_PID` property (and that means that some programs don't set it correctly)

Comment: @AndreySidorov please make a separate answer, possibly containing the code used to get properties. It is the better answer.

Comment: `xprop` does it from the cmdline.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned, you can use command line tools like `wmctrl` or `xprop`. Well behaved clients should set `_NET_WM_PID` property to be pid of the process which created main window (all popular toolkits do this for you). Note that some clients don't set it or may be on another physical machine (you can use `WM_CLIENT_MACHINE` property) - so use this information as a hint and don't rely on it to be present or accurate.  See [emwh spec at freedesktop](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html#idp6346136) for reference.

Answer (score 4):

*[Here](https://github.com/computefoundation/gnu-linux-shell-scripting/tree/master/scripts/x11_management-output_only#x11-management---output-only) are multiple great X11 window management solutions.*

Try wmctrl. Here's a script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# getwindidbypid
# 
# Get the ID of a window by PID (if the process has a window).
# 
# Usage:
#   getwindidbypid <PID>
# 

while IFS= read line; do
  if [[ "${line}" =~ (0x)([0-9a-z]+)([ ][- ][0-9]+[ ])([0-9]*) ]]; then
    winId="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    pid="${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
    if [[ "${pid}" -eq "${1}" ]]; then
      WIND_IDS+=("${winId}")
    fi
  fi
done < <(wmctrl -lp)

if [ "${#WIND_IDS[@]}" -gt 0 ]; then
  echo "${WIND_IDS[0]}"
fi
```

Example:

```
user ~ $  getwindidbypid 37248
0x05a00012
```