# get X11 window id of terminal from shell

Tags: shell, x11

How can I get the window ID of the terminal that my shell script is running in?

Background:
I need to write a script to do something based on which virtual desktop it is running in. To get the virtual desktop (not current desktop, I may change it while the script is running), I need the window ID of the terminal that the script is running in. If the script is not run from a terminal, it should fail with an error.

Comment: I know very little of `X11`, but running `env` in my terminal, I spotted an environment variable `WINDOWID`, that shows the same number in different tabs in the same terminal, but a different number in another terminal. Perhaps that's what you need?

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20580897/get-x-window-id-from-process-in-bash

Comment: @Evert that is an answer (your first comment about the environment variable), can you move it to be an answer. Then I will give you a big tick.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I know very little of X11, but running the `env` command in my terminal, I spotted an environment variable `WINDOWID`, that shows the same number in different tabs of the same terminal, but a different number in another terminal. Perhaps that's what you need?

It does appear to be an `Xterm` thing (and probably any terminal that mimicks `Xterm`s behaviour. The `xterm(1)` man page only says:

> ENVIRONMENT
>
> ```
>    Xterm sets several environment variables:
>    ...
>    WINDOWID
>         is set to the X window id number of the xterm window.
> ```

Some other possibly relevant questions with answers:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3197/how-to-identify-which-xterm-a-shell-or-process-is-running-in
- [Get X window id from process in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20580897/get-x-window-id-from-process-in-bash?lq=1)

Comment: While working in xterm and rxvt, it is not available in terminator.